# Optimal Solution for fetching, processing, saving million records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Technology Stack Used : NodeJs MongoDB 
Environment: RAM: 8GB

There is 1 million record which needs to be fetched(request made with ids) from a 3rd party provider. The Ids are available locally. The data fetched is processed and then stored in mongodb.

**Limitation of 3rd party server**
They can support only 100 ids per request.

**Environment Issue**
After 100,000 records I am facing memory issue with the following error `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory`. So Garbage collection was done in a regular interval.

After GC it took 15 hours to fetch, process and dump the 350000 records in mongo. (After certain time writing speed to mongo started deteriorating. No Index is maintained on the records as of now.)

The records occupy 1.5GB for 350,000 post processing in mongodb.

This process is to be repeated once in 24 hours, so I need to achieve it in the least possible time. Is there a better way or any technology stack to achieve/optimise this?

Comment: Show us some code! Plus the complete error message.

Comment: It sounds like you have an inefficient import process (perhaps with a memory leak in your Node.js application, given the need to force frequent GC). Without additional details on your environment and how you are processing the data it is hard to guess how to improve the efficiency. Have you done any profiling while your import is running? Is your Node.js application (or any other resource-hungry apps) running on the same server as MongoDB? What O/S and disk configuration are you using? What resource appears to be the limiting factor when you observe a slowdown?